# Endomorphisms of a projective (non-free) module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra

I've confused myself about endomorphisms of a non-free module. Here's the 
situation:

Let $R$ be a non-commutative ring, let $M\subset R^2$ be a projective left $R$-module which has two generators over $R$, say $e_1,e_2\in R^2$. Then it seems that any $R$-linear endomorphism $\varphi:M\to M$ is determined by where we send these two generators, since all elements of $M$ are of the form $ae_1+be_2$, and we have that $\varphi(ae_1+be_2)=a\varphi(e_1)+b\varphi(e_2)$. Then any endomorphism is of the form $\varphi(e_1)=a_1e_1+a_3e_2$, and $\varphi(e_2)=a_2e_1+a_4e_2$, which we can write as a matrix if we want:
$$\begin{bmatrix}a_1&a_2\\a_3&a_4\end{bmatrix}\in M_2(R).$$

But then it seems that $\text{End}_R(M)\cong M_2(R)\cong \text{End}_R(R^2)$?  This seems strange to me, so perhaps I've made an error somewhere? As a semi-related question, is the determinant of such a matrix defined the same way for this non-commutative $R$, i.e. $a_1a_4-a_2a_3$?

Comment: Not every choice of $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ yields a well-defined map, unless $M$ is free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take your favorite ring $A$ and consider $R=A\times A\times A$. As projective module take $M=A\times A\times\{0\}$, with generators $e_1=(1,0,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1,0)$.

There is no endomorphism of $M$ sending $e_1$ to $e_2$, for instance. Indeed, if $\varphi(e_1)=e_2$, we have $\varphi(e_1)=\varphi(e_1e_1)=e_1\varphi(e_1)=e_1e_2=0$, a contradiction.

Actually, the endomorphism ring of $M$ is $A^\mathrm{op}\times A^\mathrm{op}$, which is very different from $M_2(R^\mathrm{op})$.

The problem in your reasoning is that you can't *arbitrarily* choose $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$. This is possible *if* $M$ is free with basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$.

Answer (score 4):

Every endomorphism can be expressed as a matrix in the way you say.  However, that hardly defines an isomorphism $\text{End}_R(M)\cong M_2(R)$.  Indeed, it doesn't even define a function $\text{End}_R(M)\to M_2(R)$ (or $M_2(R)\to\text{End}_R(M)$).  The representation of an endomorphism as a matrix is typically not unique, since the $a_1$ and $a_3$ such that $\varphi(e_1)=a_1e_1+a_3e_2$ are typically not unique (and similarly for $a_2$ and $a_4$).  Moreover, there is no reason to think that an arbitrary matrix actually gives a well-defined endomorphism of $M$.  At best, what you get is a surjective homomorphism from a subring of $M_2(R^{op})$ (those matrices that do give well-defined homomorphisms) to $\text{End}_R(M)$.  (Note also that I wrote $R^{op}$ because composition of endomorphisms corresponds to matrix multiplication where you use the ring structure on $R$ with multiplication in reversed order; see [Noncommutative rings, matrices and homomorphisms of free modules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3307929/noncommutative-rings-matrices-and-homomorphisms-of-free-modules) for more on this.)

Usually determinants are not talked about at all for matrices over noncommutative rings as they tend to be poorly behaved.